# How to create a database which needs to be able to store same type of data each day

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm trying to create a attendence tracking website for students .where  attendence of students with respect to each day and each hour of class is stored in a table "classname" so
How can I add data into this table each day without deleting previous data..

Consider a class with students name and periods as 1st hr,2nd hr.. etc up to 5hrs per day.. and a date field..

Each day each hr the attendance is marked to this table.. so after a week or a month we could generate a report out of it..

Here comes my question, After taking attendence for one day the table is complete. so how data will be saved and the same table is used for next day.

Comment: Typically attendance would be stored in a table called attendance

Comment: Create `attendance` table with columns `date, class_id, student_id, ...` and insert data into it.

Comment: Might as well add your table definition if you want a critique. My bet is it looks like id,hour1,hour2,hour3,hour4, hour5

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have these columns in the table:

```
(
ID int primary key identity(1,1), 
fk_studentsID int foreign key(fk_studentsID) references Sudents (ID) not null,
fk_classID int foreign key(fk_classID) references Classes (ID) not null,
Date date not null, 
Hours int CHECK (Hours>=1 AND Hours<=5) not null,
Mark bit not null)
```

Then you can output the total statistics for the day or the individual student's attendance for a certain time, etc.

Comment: Doesn't tell me which class was attended?

Comment: @P.Salmon I add classes

Comment: What if I want to store the data for a week and generate a report..? If I fill the table with values in the first day ,then how can it be reused for the next day without clearing the old data ..? .Do I need to create a table each day to store the list..?

Comment: You can use this table every day, you just need to write the correct date, and then you can generate report for any time

Comment: @Asel you are right it will work if I enter attendence of every student seperately ,what I'm planning is a website with check boxes.. corresponding to each student.. that makes it much more harder..